# Bulk API V1 Query - ResultId missing when running concurrent Bulk Jobs

Tags: batch, bulk-api, c#, xml, session

When querying for the result ids of a batch on a closed Bulk (v1) query job, sometimes the result id is not returned; instead the full returned xml is:

```
<result-list xmlns="http://www.force.com/2009/06/asyncapi/dataload"/>
```

The expected response is:

```
<result-list xmlns="http://www.force.com/2009/06/asyncapi/dataload"><result>7520S000002q9sJ</result></result-list>
```

Where 7520S000002q9sJ is the result id for the requested batch.

Here is my situation:

- My custom code (C#.NET) creates a query job, closes it, check for
  completion [EDIT: this was the faulty part], then retrieves the batch results via a result id
- This issue has only occurred when running *concurrent* runs of my custom code. A re-run of my custom code with the same query and same results yields the expected results returned. A single run of the custom code has no issue.
- Results of these queries is between 2,000 to 88,000 records and completes in a matter of seconds. From this, and subsequent reruns, I surmise that Salesforce limitations on size returned is not the issue.
- Each of the query jobs created run against different objects. There is not any link between queried object and which query has this issue.
- Each of the runs of this custom code uses the same login account. There does not appear to be a direct issue of concurrency because (1) each of the jobs is able to create, run, and close a bulk job without issue and (2) there are only 3 jobs running at once and I believe the concurrency limit is 5.
- Which of the 3 runs of the custom code that fails to retrieve a result id is inconsistent, usually only 1 or 2 fail but occasionally all 3 fail in this manner.
- When viewed from the Salesforce web interface, all of the jobs have a valid query, and valid results and a valid batch id.
- No error message from Salesforce has ever been given (such as too many concurrent users, thresholds exceeded, etc)
- log messages verify that the correct request is being sent to Salesforce (correct jobid and correct batchid) for any given run

**What is causing Salesforce to return an empty result-list, when by all appearances, there are valid and available results to be retrieved?**

My hunch is that there is an issue with threading or concurrent Salesforce sessions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Result was a bug in the custom code that prematurely determined results were ready to retrieve from the bulk query job. My criteria was checking *job* completion instead of *batch* completion.

> **What is causing Salesforce to return an empty result-list, when by all
>   appearances, there are valid and available results to be retrieved?**

This happens when the batch is queried before it has completed processing.

Resolution was finally tracked down by viewing the timestamp on debug statements of "`Checking when Bulk job is completed...`" and "`... completed`". The "`... completed`" message had a timestamp before the End Time listed on the batch job via Salesforce interface.

A few questions answered:

- **why was the issue only present with concurrent runs of my custom job?** - concurrent jobs creates a higher demand on Salesforce which often manifests itself as batches taking longer to process but the latency for job closure did not change.
- **why wasn't the issue detectable in Sandbox?** - our test/Sandbox has significantly less data than production. This meant that the difference between the time a job closed and its batch completion was negligible due to smaller query results to process.